# Select value using 'EditValue'

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have one LookUpEdit control that I populate with one `DataTable`. This is the content of my `Datatable`

```
   ID   || Description
=========================
   4    || Example one
   2    || Example two
   0    || Example three
   1    || Example Four
   3    || Example Five
```

This is my LookUpEdit configuration:

```
LUEControl.Properties.DataSource = _MyDataTable
LUEControl.Properties.ValueMember = "ID"
LUEControl.Properties.DisplayMember = "Description"
```

For what I have been reading if I set `LUEControl.EditValue = 0` in the Shown event when the form is loaded the `LookUpEdit` control should show the 'Example three' item but it shows nothing even if the control is already populate I do that before the `LUEControl.EditValue = 0` instruction.

**Why I can't make that the control show the item I pass in the `EditValue`?**

If you need more info just ask, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct and should work. Make sure that the ID column type matches the type of the value you assigned to the EditValue property (Int32 in your case). This is the only reason why the LookUpEdit cannot find a corresponding record in the data source.

Comment: I actually done this before but in this case doesn't work, the only diference is that before the Id I get from the database was `numeric(2,0)` and in this case is `numeric(9,0)`. Or there is a way to get the `ItemIdex` by the `ValueMember` that in this case is the ID?.